# VS Code drag tab to new window

Tags: visual-studio-code

Instead of splitting windows, is it possible to drag the tabs to a new window in Visual Studio Code like Sublime, PHPstorm or Chrome?

When I drag a tab onto the desktop, it will copy the file.

Comment: Why the heck does simply dragging a tab out of VSCode not work? I was shocked when I tried doing that and it made a copy of the file I dragged out to my desktop lol. There has got to be a extension that makes dragging a tab out of VSCode, open that file in a new instance of VSCode. That is how Sublime Text works be default and every other program I have ever used...

Comment: this is WinDoze

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This is a [very highly upvoted issue request in Github for Floating Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10121).

Until they support it, you can try the following *workarounds*:

#### 1. Duplicate Workspace in New Window <sup>[[1]](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10121#issuecomment-430137243)</sup>

The [Duplicate Workspace in new Window Command](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_duplicate-workspace-in-new-window) was added in v1.24 (May 2018) to sort of address this.

1. Open up Keyboard Shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Map `workbench.action.duplicateWorkspaceInNewWindow` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> or whatever you'd like

[image: Duplicate Workspace in New Window]

#### 2. Open Active File in New Window <sup>[[2]](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10121#issuecomment-436791520)</sup>

Rather than manually open a new window and dragging the file, you can do it all with a single command.

1. Open Active File in New Window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>

[image: Open Active File in New Window]

#### 3. New Window with Same File <sup>[[3]](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10121#issuecomment-315778189)</sup>

As AllenBooTung also pointed out, you can open/drag any file in a separate blank instance.

1. Open New Window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
2. Drag tab into new window

#### 4. Open Workspace and Folder Simultaneously <sup>[[4]](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10121#issuecomment-426858134)</sup>

VS Code will not allow you to open the same folder in two different instances, but you can use [Workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44629890/1366033) to open the same directory of files in a side by side instance.

1. Open Folder <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
2. Save Current Project As a Workspace
3. Open Folder <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

---

For **any workaround**, also consider setting setting up auto save so the documents are kept in sync by updating the `files.autoSave` setting to `afterDelay`, `onFocusChange`, or `onWindowChange`

[image: AutoSave]

Comment: the issue on github is open since 2016, and they closed it in 2018 saying that it's on the team's radar... lol, rip.

Comment: It actually looks like the issue is still 'open', but just 'locked' for further comments.  That's probably pretty reasonable for an issue with 3k+ reactions already, as it's not likely to invite more helpful feedback and seems like it's on the team's radar.

Comment: I'm very happy with the `Ctrl-k,o` solution. VS Code is a breakthrough product for me. After 40 years in the business I have finally found an improvement on notepad++. so I'm happy to let them set their own priorities.

Comment: none of this solutions work if you are connected to a dev container (using Remote Development extension)

Answer (score 37):

#### ■New Window with Same File

1. Press CTRL+SHIFT+N to create a default new window.
2. Drag the tab into this new window.

#### ■Command Line

1. Add `C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code` to system path.
2. Type this command in terminal.

`PS D:\xampp\htdocs\bi>code vendor/bin/../composer/autoload_files.php -n`

#### ■AutoHotKey

1. Compile this `ahk` script and execute it.

```
+!v::
clipboardstr := Clipboard
run, code %clipboardstr% -n
return
```

2. Right click on the tab and then press `shift+ alt+ c` in vscode can copy file path to clipboard.
3. `shift+ alt+ v` open this page to new window.

Comment: Simplest solution.

Comment: not that simple, way more keystrokes and clicks, and inferior.

is there a way to customize the behavior such that we can simply drag to create a new window like sublimetext allows?

Comment: Doesn't work with all tabs, especially git comparison tabs.

Comment: Doesn't currently work with Remote SSH sessions, ergo codespaces.

Answer (score 1):

[This has been added in the newest update (1.85.x)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10121#issuecomment-1836212530)

Just drag the tab into another screen (or outside vs code) it will open in as a new window